# Display "99+" if a number is greater than some value I assign

Tags: angular, conditional-operator, string-interpolation

I have a dynamic numbers count that comes to my notification variable.

I'm using the ternary operator to display that number if it is less than 99, otherwise, I want to display "99+".

I have tried this:

```
<div class="notification-badge" *ngIf="unreadNotificationsCount > 0">
  {{(unreadNotificationsCount < 99) ? {{unreadNotificationsCount}} : '99+'}}
```

..but it doesn't allow string interpolation inside the ternary

Comment: {{(unreadNotificationsCount < 99) ? unreadNotificationsCount : '99+'}}

Comment: @ritaj you need double braces to bind data to html. Your solution will not be binded/rendered, it is just a string/text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too many `{`s.

```
{{ (unreadNotificationsCount < 99) ? unreadNotificationsCount : '99+' }}
```

should work.

Comment: I need this variable in interpollation {{unreadNotificationsCount }}. Would it display data anw?

Comment: The outer `{{ }}` already mean "evaluate the expression (on every change detection cycle)". No need to repeat it inside the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `{{}}` within another `{{}}`

Try this:

```
{{(unreadNotificationsCount < 99) ? unreadNotificationsCount : '99+'}}
```

Comment: This one did it! Thanks you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Would you please upvote and accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. For more reusable stuff you can use custom pipe for that.

your-component.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="yourNumber">
    {{ yourNumber | transalateNumber }}
</div>
```

transalate-number.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({name: 'transalateNumber'})
export class TransalateNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): string {
        if (value <= 99) {
            return value.toString();
        } else {
            return '99+';
        }
    }
}
```

2. Try to format your number in your .ts file.

your-component.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="yourNumber">
    {{ formatNumber(yourNumber) }}
</div>
```

your-component.component.ts

```
...
yourNumber: number = 100;

formatNumbar(value: number): string {
    if (value <= 99) {
        return value.toString();
    } else {
        return '99+'
    }
...
```